# Why does notifyListeners() not update consumer?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

In my app built with Flutter, I am using the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to add state management to my app. Additionally, I am using the [shared preferences package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to keep track of the login state of my user (token based). The app consumes a Laravel API that makes use of [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum).

Everything is working as expected. However, after logging out the user and logging back in with a different user, causes the data of the previous user to be shown. I noticed the token of the old user keeps persisting in the providers, which causes old data to load.

**main.dart**

```
Future main() async {
  await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => AuthProvider(),
        child: Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (context, authProvider, child) {
          return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoryProvider>(
                    create: (context) => CategoryProvider(authProvider)),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<TransactionProvider>(
                    create: (context) => TransactionProvider(authProvider)),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<ProfileProvider>(
                    create: (context) => ProfileProvider(authProvider))
              ],
              child: MaterialApp(
                title: 'Flutter App',
                routes: {
                  '/': (context) {
                    final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
                    return authProvider.isAuthenticated ? Home() : Login();
                  },
                  '/login': (context) => Login(),
                  '/register': (context) => Register(),
                  '/profile': (context) => Profile(),
                  '/categories': (context) => Categories(),
                },
              ));
        }));
  }
}
```

Given the above example, I was expecting for any change to my AuthProvider, to rebuild the Providers that are listed in the Consumer widget.

**auth_provider.dart**

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isAuthenticated = false;
  late String token;

  AuthProvider() {
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    this.token = await getToken();

    if (this.token.isNotEmpty) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
    }

    ApiService apiService = ApiService(this.token);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ApiService apiService = ApiService('');

  Future<void> register(String name, String email, String password,
      String passwordConfirm, String deviceName) async {
    
    this.token = await apiService.register(name, email, password, passwordConfirm, deviceName);
    setToken(this.token);
    this.isAuthenticated = true;

    notifyListeners();

  }

  Future<void> login(String email, String password, String deviceName) async {
    this.token = await apiService.login(email, password, deviceName);
    setToken(this.token);
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    this.token = '';
    this.isAuthenticated = false;

    setToken(this.token);

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.clear();

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> setToken(token) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('token', token);
  }

  Future<String> getToken() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('token') ?? '';
  }
}
```

In the `logout()` function, I am clearing the token.

**category_provider.dart**

```
class CategoryProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Category> categories = [];
  late ApiService apiService;
  late AuthProvider authProvider;

  CategoryProvider(AuthProvider authProvider) {
    this.authProvider = authProvider;
    this.apiService = ApiService(authProvider.token);

    init();
  }

  Future init() async {
    categories = await apiService.fetchCategories();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> addCategory(String name) async {
    try {
      Category addedCategory = await apiService.addCategory(name);
      categories.add(addedCategory);

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (Exception) {
      print(Exception);
    }
  }

  // omitted functions
}
```

The ApiService is a class that receives the passed token and does API calls for the providers.

**api.dart**

```
class ApiService {
  late String token;

  ApiService(String token) {
    this.token = token;
  }

  final String baseUrl = dotenv.env['APP_URL'].toString() + '/api/';

  Future<List<Category>> fetchCategories() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl + 'categories'), headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
      HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
    });
    List categories = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];

    return categories.map((category) => Category.fromJson(category)).toList();
  }

  // omitted functions
}
```

Why does the `notifiyListeners()` in the logout function of `auth_provider.dart` not trigger the consumers to rebuild? Am I missing something else that might cause this issue?

**Update after answer**

In the providers array of `main.dart`, I changed the ChangeNotifierProvider to [ChangeNotifierProxyProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider-class.html). The difference is that the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider allows for a `update()` callback, so the provider can get updated if `AuthProvider` updates.

**Code example:**

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthProvider, CategoryProvider>(
    create: (context) => CategoryProvider(authProvider),
    update: (context, authProvider, categoryProvider) => CategoryProvider(authProvider)
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `Consumer` is being updated.  Your `Provider`s aren't recreating their values.**

`Provider.create` is only called once, the first time that the value is needed.  After a user logs out and another user logs in, the same `CategoryProvider` instance still exists, so as far as `Provider` knows, there's no reason to create another one.  The `ApiService` instance stored in `CategoryProvider` still uses the old token, which causes old data to load.

To update the token, you will need to either update or recreate `CategoryProvider` with the new token.  One option for this is `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`, which provides an `update` callback parameter.